# What is the best freemium online service to make your own word cards?

Tags: learning

I used to compile my own dictionary on a Russian website. Using several dictionaries as well as surfing the internet, I made about 2,000 entries (it included both words and idioms).

Unfortunately, it was then destroyed due to some glitch on the website's part, I guess. I was heartbroken and gave it up for a couple of years but I recently started to realize that my skills and lexicon have shrunken. I'm pretty sure it's because of it. You see, that custom dictionary included hand-picked sentences, and I used to regularly pronounce them aloud which helped me remember and incorporate them into my active vocabulary. I have a partial list of the words from the ruined dictionary and I realized that I forgot some of them entirely, as if I see them for the first time.

Anyway, I think it would make sense to resume my lexicographic practice and was wondering whether there's some free online service that allows you to make your own dictionary entries (like word cards but more detailed), secures them well, and has an option of downloading them for backup purposes. I need a lot of space for all definitions and example sentences (plus the possibility of adding pictures).

Like [Anki](http://jpegshare.net/11/b0/11b0aa0dc25104d9e1f6397776f93edd.png.html), it doesn't meet my requirements. It also would be helpful if the website used those cards in some sort of personal games or tests that I would be offered to take to better remember the words. I don't have a smartphone so don't offer Android or iOS apps.

I'm looking for some free or freemium options (maybe Quizlet is good, for example, but it's a subscription service).

Answer (score 0):

[Quizlet](https://quizlet.com/) is the one I use. It’s quite feature intensive and most of the features are free.  It should be able to do everything you need it to.

Comment: It says the first seven days are free and then a few bucks per month

Comment: I don’t think so… I’ve been using it for years for free.

Comment: Where do I add example sentences (https://jpeg.im/gno7)?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Please look at the screenshot and tell me how do I add example sentences, I don't see such an option

Comment: I did look at the screenshot.  I’m not sure what you mean by “how do I add an example sentence?” What’s an example sentence?

Comment: These are example sentences: https://jpeg.im/gnoe

Comment: Ok, so you’re trying to use quizlet to learn English.  You can put example sentences in parenthesis on either side depending on if you want to see it before or after you answer the question